# Как переместить минимальный елемент после максимального в списке

Tags: c++, c

Как переместить минимальный елемент после максимального в списке.

***Дан список из последовательности натуральных чисел. Добавить в список после максимального элемента минимальный.***

У меня есть половина  программы но,я не знаю как это сделать.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
struct List                             
{
int n;
List *next;}   
*start, *last;

void min1(void)
{
int min;
List *smin,*g;
    min=start->n;
g=start->next;

while(g!=0){                      //Поиск мин
    if(min>g->n)
    {
        min=g->n;
        smin=g;
    }
    g=g->next;
}
printf("\n");
printf ("Min=%d",min);
}
void max1(void)
{

int max;
    List *smin,*smax,*ssmin,*ssmax,*g;
max=start->n;
g=start->next;

while(g!=0){
    if(max<g->n)
    {
        max=g->n;
        smax=g;                     //Поиск макс
    }
    g=g->next;
}
printf("\n");
printf ("Max=%d",max);
}
void change( void )
{
List *s, *l;
s = start;
l = last;
int h;
h = s -> n;
s -> n = l -> n;            // Меняем местами первый и последний
l -> n = h;
}

void fill_list( int N )                 
{
List *p;
int i;
if ( start == NULL )                
{
    start = new List;
    start -> n = 1;
    start -> next = NULL;
    last = start;                               // Заполняем список
}
for( i = 2; i <= N; i++ )           
{
    p = new List;
    p -> n = i;
    p -> next = NULL;
    last -> next = p;
    last = p;
}
}
int main()
{
start = NULL;
last = NULL;
List *p1, *p2, *p,*g;
printf( "VVedite razmer spiska\n" );
int M,max,min; scanf( "%d", &M );           //Вводим размер списка

fill_list( M );                 //Заполняем
p = start;

while( p != NULL )
{
    printf("| %2d |", p -> n );     //Выводим
    p = p -> next;
}
max1();
min1();
change();
p = start;
printf("\n");                   
while( p != NULL ) 
{
    printf("| %2d |", p -> n );     //Выводим смену последнего и первого 
элемент
    p = p -> next;
}

p = start; p1 = start; p2 = NULL;
while (p != NULL)           
{
    p1 = p -> next;             
    delete p;
    p = p1;
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: Обойти все элементы списка, запоминая указатели на элемент с минимальным и элемент с максимальным значением. После чего в поле `next` элемента с максимальным значением записать ранее запомненный  указатель на элемент с минимальным значением. Теперь вы знаете, как это сделать.

Comment: А вы не можете написать фрагмент как это сделать?Просто я только учу списки,и у меня плохо получаеться с этим

Comment: Тут уже есть [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505681/232) на такой же вопрос.